# How to find $u$ and $v$ for $(xu-yv)+i(xv+yu)=1$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm reading Beardon's *Algebra and Geometry*.

> To find the multiplicative inverse $z^{\small -1}$ of a complex number $z$ we adopt a common strategy in mathematics, namely we first assume that the inverse exists and then find an explicit expression for it. It is then quite legitimate to start with this expression (which does exist) and then verify that it has the desired properties. Given the complex number $z=x+iy$, then, we assume that $z^{\small -1}$ exists, write $z^{\small -1}=u+iv$, and then impose the condition $zz^{\small
> -1}$=1. This yields:
>
> $$(xu-yv)+i(xv+yu)=1\tag{1}$$
>
> so that $xu-yv=1$ and $xv+yu=0$. Thus $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$. So, for any non-zero $z$, say $z=x+iy$ (where $x^2+y^2\neq 0$), we define
>
> $$ z^{\small -1}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}+i \left(\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}\right)=\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}\tag{2}$$
>
> It is now easy to verify that $zz^{\small -1}=1=z^{\small -1}z$, so that $z^{\small -1}$ is indeed the multiplicative inverse of $z$; thus *every non-zero complex number has a multiplicative inverse.*

He made $u=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$ and $v=\frac{-y}{x^2+y^2}$, I used that and checked that it is true but the process he used to such $u$ and $v$ is unknown to me. How to do that or how's the name of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $xv + yu = 0$, you can alternately solve for $u$ and $v$. For example, $u = \frac{-xv}{y}$. Substitute this into the other equation and rearrange, and you get that $v = \frac{-y}{x^2 + y^2}$. Solve for $v$ at first and substitute to get the other.

Comment: I understand it works, but what's the underlying principle of this? I'm not sure on how to ask but I guess that it would need to be reduced to axioms.

Comment: @Gustavo: I don't know what you mean by underlying principle. You have a system of two linear equations with two unknowns. There are many ways to solve it. If I had to name a 'principle,' I would say that you reduce what you don't know by using what you do know. But like any other big statement, it doesn't always work either.